# Определение местоположения устройства android в отдельном потоке

Tags: java, android, gps

Хочу вынести определение местоположения в отдельный поток, для того, чтобы UI не терял отзывчивость. Читал про то, что системные службы можно запускать только в главном потоке (в котором работает UI). В дальнейшем хочу поместить определение местоположения в Сервис. Два вопроса:

1. Оправдано ли создание отдельного потока? если да
2. Как можно обойти ограничение на создание только в главном потоке?

P.S. На данный момент определение местоположения реализовано через отдельный класс GeoDef, общение с UI происходит через статические переменные класса GeoDef.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текущее месторасположение определяется следующим образом

в манифесте прописываете:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
```

в Activity:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Использование сервиса для этих целей не оправдано. Если Вы хотите получать данные о новом месторасположении плюс ко всему предложенному — используйте *LocationListener*. [Здесь пример[(https://stackoverflow.com/a/10917500/5292979).

А вот ту логику, которая у вас есть при изменении месторасположения, можно инкапсулировать в отдельный класс.

"общение с UI происходит через статические переменные класса GeoDef" - плохое решение.

Comment: Не указал то, что необходимо получать информацию о местоположении постоянно, даже когда приложение свернуто, в таком случае использование сервиса оправдано?

Comment: нет не оправданно, для этого нужно пользоваться LocationListener - я это написал, при изменении месторасположения будет дёргаться его метод LocationListener onLocationChanged(Location location) - в нём и прописывайте вашу логику

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Но допустим, если экран погашен, а координаты нужно получать и передавать по bluetooth, например. То в таком случае, полагаю, что сервис использовать целесообразно для обеих задач(получение и отправка)?

Comment: да, в таком случае оправдан